# Grouping Duplicate key values of an array and displaying the count in N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
{
"brands": [
  {
    "value": "brand1"
  },
  {
    "value": "brand1"
  },
  {
    "value": "brand2"
  }
],
"count": 3,
"name": "Windows"
}
```

I have an document like this in that , How can I group the array contents with the similar value and get the count of it  ? Something like below . Can someone help me with this ?

```
{
"brands": [
{
  "value": "brand1",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "value": "brand2",
  "count":1
}
],
"count": 3,
"name": "Windows"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use subquery expression reconstruct ARRAY based on your needs. Afterwords do ARRAY_SUM() on the array value to get outside total count.

```
SELECT d.*,  brands, ARRAY_SUM(brands[*].`count`) AS count
FROM default AS d
LET brands =  (SELECT b.`value`, COUNT(1) AS count
               FROM d.brands AS b
               GROUP BY b.`value`)
WHERE ....
```

If outside count already right

```
SELECT d.*,  
     (SELECT b.`value`, COUNT(1) AS count
               FROM d.brands AS b
               GROUP BY b.`value`) AS brands
FROM default AS d
WHERE ....
```